anthology for middle schoolers with a blue cover and white text/illustration of tree
I've been scouring the internet for an anthology I read in middle school (sometime between 2007-2010) that combined science fiction and fantasy short stories. I don't recall much except it was a hardcover book with a dark blue background and a white tree as the main illustration (kind of like the crest of Gondor), and was probably 400-500 pages. There are so many niche anthologies that I've found it hard to narrow down so far, I'm hoping someone here might know it!
There is one story in particular that I recall, about a girl who is preparing to go through a physical condition that I now assume was a metaphor for/literally about menstruation. The setting seemed like an alternate Victorian universe, and the girl is taken to a (bed)room to experience this condition, while other women gather to care for her and share their wisdom.
Unfortunately I don't remember much else, but I do know that anthology changed something subtle in me as a reader and I'd very much like to revisit it if possible!

Do you recall any other stories at all?
